# Alternative to multidex-android for compiling POI libraries in build.gradle

Tags: android, excel, gradle, apache-poi, android-multidex

I've compiled the POI library like this:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.17'
```

But i found this problem during the building:

> Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed
>   64K. Learn how to resolve this issue at
>   https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

So instead of enabling the multidex that causes me many other problems, I'm searching for an alternative solution like **including only a part of the POI library** since I use it only for .xls (Excel file) parsing.

*(I have already found the [Jxl library](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/), but I have also already written some code using POI).*